# why doesn't the content in the row work, which should be in the right corner

Tags: flutter

why doesn't the content in the row work, which should be in the right corner. I have used positioned top:0 right:0 and even Align Alignment.centerRight still has no effect

```
Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text('Stefany'),
                        Text('Employee'),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.purple,
                            height: 20,
                            child: ListView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                Text('Age: 32'),
                                Text('Color: Blue'),
                                Text('City: New York'),
                                Text('Country: Rusia'),
]
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

**this doesn't work:**

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    Text('Age: 32'),
    Text('Color: Blue'),
    Text('City: New York'),                                
    Text('Country: Rusia'),
])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUMxt.png)

Comment: remove expanded and listview . It is working separately

Comment: or give sime size and width of ROW

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working code: Explanation is after the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        const Text('Stefany'),
        const Text('Employee'),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
            height: 20,
            child: const SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 400,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text('Age: 32'),
                    Text('Color: Blue'),
                    Text('City: New York'),
                    Text('Country: Rusia'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Change I made is made the `List` to `SingleChildScrollView` as your content in only a single child. Further more `SingleChildScrollView` or any other scroll view does not allow its children to occupy all constraints applied to its parent. Each child of a scroll view must have his own constraints.